# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'category_encoders'

Tags: python

I tried few way to install category encoders and it never works.

Here are the ways I did, each installation shows success. anyone has any suggestion? Thanks

```
pip install --upgrade category_encoders
```

```
conda install -c conda-forge category_encoders
```

```
from category_encoders.target_encoder import TargetEncoder

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [17], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from category_encoders.target_encoder import TargetEncoder

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'category_encoders'
```

Comment: Type "pip list" and see if this module is on the list. If is not then is because it wasn't installed.

Comment: thanks, I just did and it shows it is installed already (xgboost) C:\Users\test>pip list
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
Bottleneck        1.3.5
category-encoders 2.5.0

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you are using the same python version, when you install the library and you run it.
2. my suggestion is create new virtual environment and activate then install all library that needed, then run your app from there.

Comment: I did create a new anacondas environment and install all library under that. How do I know they are using same python?

Comment: Open the python terminal in the terminal and see the version, then see if the pip version is the same.

If you are in Windows go to the root directory of Python and search for the paste "Scripts", there will show all libraries that you install.

Comment: Other thing that you could do is to see all programs that you have installed and see if there is more than one python. I recommend you to have just one

Comment: first, activate your virtual environment that you have created. from there check python version : python --version. then check if library is there pip list or pip3 list for python3

Comment: I remove the library from pip and install it using conda. for this case, how do i check they have same python version? Thanks

Comment: so the steps is : you activate your environtment that you already created, after you activated (mean, you already into that environment), then install your library. then in after install successfully , from theat terminal, try in to the interactive mode : just type python. then try to import again : from category_encoders.target_encoder import TargetEncoder

Answer (score 0):

try this

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder